# Delphi copy generic object with unknown base type at compile time

Tags: delphi, generics

I would like to copy generic object but its type can only be obtained by the "class of" construct at runtime as the source object type may be different (TItem or TSpecificItem etc.):

```
type
  TItem = class
  //...
    procedure Assign(Source: TItem);virtual; abstract; //edit
  end;

  TSpecificItem = class(TItem)
  //...
  end;

  TEvenMoreSpecificItem = class(TSpecificItem)
  //...
  end;

  TItemClass = class of TItem;

  TItemContainer = class
    FItems: TObjectList<TItem>; //edit
    procedure Assign(Source: TObject); //edit
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TItem; inline; //edit
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Item: TItem); inline; //edit
    function Count: Integer; //edit;
    function ItemClass: TItemClass; virtual; abstract;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TItem read GetItem write SetItem; //edit
  end;

  TItemContainer<T: TItem> = class(TItemContainer)
  //...
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): T; inline; //edit
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Item: T); inline; //edit
    function ItemClass: TItemClass; override;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default; //edit
  end;

//start of edit
function TItemContainer.Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := FItems.Count;
end;

function TItemContainer.GetItem(Index: Integer): TItem;
begin
  Result := FItems[Index];
end;

procedure TItemContainer.SetItem(Index: Integer; Item: TItem);
begin
  FItems[Index].Assign(Item);
end;

procedure TItemContainer.Assign(Source: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Item: TItem;
  Cls: TClass;
begin
  if Source is TItemContainer then
  begin
    FItems.Clear;
    for I := 0 to TItemContainer(Source).Count - 1 do
    begin
      Item := TItemContainer(Source).Items[I];
      Cls := Item.ClassType;
      Item := TItemClass(Cls).Create;
      Item.Assign(TItemContainer(Source).Items[I]);
      FItems.Add(Item);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TItemContainer<T>.GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := T(inherited GetItem(Index));
end;

procedure TItemContainer<T>.SetItem(Index: Integer; Item: T);
begin
  inherited SetItem(Index, Item);
end;
//end of edit

function TItemContainer<T>.ItemClass: TItemClass;
begin
  Result := TItemClass(GetTypeData(PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)))^.ClassType);
end;

function CopyGenericObject(Source: TItemContainer): TItemContainer;
var
  Cls: TItemClass;
begin
  Cls := Source.ItemClass;
  Result := TItemContainer<Cls>.Create; // compiler reports error "incompatible types"
  Result.Assign(Source);
end;

// edit:
procedure DoCopy;
var
  Source: TItemContainer<TEvenMoreSpecificItem>;
  Dest: TItemContainer;
begin
  Source := TItemContainer<TEvenMoreSpecificItem>.Create; // for example
  //add some items to Source
  Dest := CopyGenericObject(Source);
  //use the result somewhere
end;
```

I must Use Delphi XE.

I've found
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Overview_of_Generics

> Dynamic instantiation
>
> Dynamic instantiation at run time is not supported.

Is it what I want to do?

Comment: Beyond the fact that your syntax is wrong, what you attempt is in general impossible. You might not have actually instantiated the concrete type `TDCollection<Cls>` at compile time. Instead of asking how to implement your solution to the problem, please ask how to solve the problem. That way will lead to useful help.

Comment: Syntax corrected. Thank you that answer is sufficient. I can solve my problem in another way but I just wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: What I mean by syntax being wrong is that `Cls` is not known at runtime and generic instantiations must be. You can create instances using RTTI but you have to have instantiated the type.

Comment: The reason I am not attempting to show you how is that I suspect that you are going about this entirely the wrong way. It's clear that you don't really know what you are doing. You should face up to this and ask for help coming up with a good solution to your problem, rather than asking how to implement your solution to the problem which I bet is the wrong solution.

Comment: @David let's discuss it further below the answer which I acknowledged if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, what you are looking for is to implement a routine that will create an instance of a class of the same type as a given source.  This can be done like this :

```
type
  TItemContainerclass = class of TItemContainer;

function CopyGenericObject(Source: TItemContainer): TItemContainer;
begin
  Result := TItemContainerclass(Source.ClassType).Create; 
end;
```

Also, you can simplify the ItemClass routine to

```
function TItemContainer<T>.ItemClass: TItemClass;
begin
  Result := T;
end;
```

Note that this will only create a new *instance* and not a *copy* of the source, but since your code doesn't show any attempt to copy the object and only create a new instance, I presumed this is your intended result.

Note : This works in Delphi 10, I don't have access to XE to test it.

Comment: TItemContainerclass(Source.ClassType).Create works but it is not a solution for Generics (with `< ... >`)

Comment: A solution for generics is not required by the problem as presented here.

Comment: Does not work. Source.ClassType reports inaccessible value and when calling TItemContainerclass(Source.ClassType).Create; exception occurs.

Comment: Then "Source" is most likely "nil" or not initialized.

Comment: @tk_ You have a defect in your code. This code works correctly. As Ken says, you are not passing a valid `Source`.

Comment: It works! Sorry I made another mistake when rewriting your solution. Thanks a lot, is much better than the solution below.

Comment: The next problem is that you don't have a virtual constructor. It amazes me that you won't tell us your actual problem. Anyway, I've given all I can here.

Comment: @David: There is virtual constructor of course. I cannot rewrite entire code here, but the problem was indeed the question. I appreciate your help a much, but I don't understand what more info would you like. Do you need to explain why I want to copy those? I think it is little bit off topic...

Comment: @tk_ I think your solution is wrong, based on intuition, but I can't see the problem. I've said that many times. You don't agree. Fine.

Comment: @David ok then I will try to explain more in detail. I edited the original code once more (see edit comments, the code compiles except for the error discussed and solved here). The problem was that I could not modify the class layout but I needed to implement new copy/assign method for entire TItemContainer including its subclass TItemContainer<T>. The reason was I needed to pass the copy of entire container to a modal dialog for local work. If user presses OK the work copy of the container is copied back and if user presses Cancel the work copy is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Cls := Source.ItemClass;
```

will create the `TItemClass` instance at run time only. For Generics, the compiler needs to know the type at compile time. Without knowing it, the compiler can not generate the binary code which implements your specific `TItemContainer<Cls>`. Or, said in other words, `Cls` must not be a variable, it has to be a specific class type, known at compile time.

So for example these will compile:

```
Result := TItemContainer<TSpecificItem>.Create;
```

or

```
Result := TItemContainer<TEvenMoreSpecificItem>.Create;
```

but not this

```
Result := TItemContainer</* type will be known later */>.Create;
```

because the compiler is not able to come back later and complete the binary application code based on the actual type of `Cls`.

Comment: Ok. it means the only approach I can use here is `if Cls = TSpecificItem then Result := TItemContainer<TSpecificItem>.Create; else if Cls = TEvenMoreSpecificItem then Result := TItemContainer<TEvenMoreSpecificItem>.Create; else if Cls =...` ?

Comment: So for each subclass I need separate constructor call. It seems to be the only solution of above question though.

Comment: @tk As I have explained, it can be done with rtti so long as the type has been instantiated. Would have been far better if you had asked about the problem that led to the question.

Comment: @David But this is the problem. I need to assign one container of items to another, exact copy. Without generics no problem, with generics this problem. I don't know what you mean with the rtti solution.

Comment: You aren't assigning anything. At the moment we are working out how to instantiate the container. Which can be done with rtti so long as the type is intantiated. I'm guessing you don't know what it means to instantiate a generic type. Which is why you don't understand me. If you don't understand that it makes life hard. Reading the documentation would plug that knowledge defecit. If you won't tell us the underlying problem I don't think you'll get very much from this.

Comment: @mjn It is perfectly possible to instantiate instances of generic types at runtime, even if the type parameters are only known at runtime. It requires RTTI and that the generic **type** has been instantiated.

Comment: @David. I don't think there was too much misunderstanding here, but I made another mistakes in my code (not shown and discussed here). That's why the simple Ken's solution initially did not work for me before I asked here and now it works. Naturally Source parameter has been instantiated with certain TItem subclass before calling CopyGenericObject.

Answer (score -1):

You can make CopyGenericObject function as a method of your generic object instead of stand-alone function:

```
TItemContainer<T: TItem> = class(TItemContainer)
  ...
  function Copy: TItemContainer<T>;
end;
```

In this case, it "knows" at compile-time, what class to create just because there are now several of them (one for each Instantiated type) after compiler did its work, each making copy of itself.

There is one more trick which may be useful in your case: how to copy various objects. For example, you have common class TAnimal and its descendants: TCat and TDog. You store them in TItemContainer, that's the whole point of inheritance that you can do it and treat them generally. Now, you want to implement creating a copy of this container and you don't know at compile time, which elements will be dogs and which will be cats. Standart method is to define abstract function Copy in TAnimal:

```
TAnimal = class
  public
    ...
    function Copy: TAnimal; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

and then implement it in each descendant, so then you can copy your TItemContainer like this:

```
    function TItemContainer<T>.Copy: TItemContainer<T>;
    var i: T;
    begin
      Result:=TItemContainer<T>.Create;
      for i in Items do 
 //I don't know exact structure of your container,   
 //maybe that's more like
 // for j:=0 to Count-1 do begin
 //   i:=Items[j];
 //but I hope it's obvious what happens here
        Result.Add(i.copy as T);
    end;
```

So if you have container of cats, then i.copy will return TAnimal (but actually a cat) which will be cast to TCat at last. It works but a bit ugly.

In delphi I came up with better solution: make this `copy` a constructor, not a function:

```
TAnimal = class
  public
    ...
    constructor Copy(source: TAnimal); virtual;
end;
```

In that case copying your container is like this:

```
function TItemContainer<T>.Copy: TItemContainer<T>;
var i,j: T;
begin
  Result:=TItemContainer<T>.Create;
  for i in Items do
    Result.Add(T.Copy(i));
end;
```

no extra casting which is good. What's more, you can for example derive your classes from TPersistent and implement Assign procedure everywhere you need (very useful thing) and then once and for all write a copy constructor:

```
TAnimal = class(TPersistent)
  public
    constructor Copy(source: TPersistent); //or maybe source: TAnimal
end;

//implementation
constructor TAnimal.Copy(source: TPersistent);
begin
  Create;
  Assign(source);
end;
```

Comment: The type `T` is not known at compile time, so this is all irrelevant, -1